Find out when an unmanaged package was installed in Production
When using this command:
sf package version list --released --verbose --json

output:
    {
      "Package2Id": "12345somestring",
      "Branch": null,
      "Tag": null,
      "MajorVersion": 3,
      "MinorVersion": 13,
      "PatchVersion": 0,
      "BuildNumber": 1,
      "Id": "12345somestring",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionId": "12345somestring",
      "ConvertedFromVersionId": null,
      "Name": "12345somestring",
      "NamespacePrefix": null,
      "Package2Name": "MyPackage",
      "Description": "12345somestring",
      "Version": "3.1.0.1",
      "IsPasswordProtected": false,
      "IsReleased": true,
      "CreatedDate": "2024-05-23 13:00",
      "LastModifiedDate": "2024-05-27 07:50",
      "InstallUrl": "",
      "CodeCoverage": "87%",
      "HasPassedCodeCoverageCheck": true,
      "ValidationSkipped": false,
      "AncestorId": "N/A",
      "AncestorVersion": "N/A",
      "Alias": "",
      "IsOrgDependent": "No",
      "ReleaseVersion": "60.0",
      "BuildDurationInSeconds": 935,
      "HasMetadataRemoved": "N/A",
      "CreatedBy": "",
      "Language": "en_US"
    }

I'm getting everything I need except for the install date in production, which  command/flag should I use?

You would need to look for the installation date in the package details within the Salesforce UI.
